# Selenium Python click command - error message

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click

```
<tr>
   <td>Wed Sep 28, 2016 9:45a.m.</td>
   <td>Dr. Smiley Schutes</td>
   <td>Medicine followup</td>
   <td>
   <td>Exam 1</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Balance Due</td>
   <td align="left">2</td>
   <td>
   <td style="text-align: right;">
      <div class="btn-group">
         <a class="btn btn-small btn-link" href="/appointments/37135832">
            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
               Edit Appointment
         </a>
         <a class="btn btn-small" target="_blank" href="/clinical_note/edit/37135832/lock/">
            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
               View Note
         </a>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

From the above HTML, the XPath below identifies the correct button to click for more information.

```
.//*[@id='id_past_appointments']//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]]//a[normalize-space(.)='View Note']
```

However, when I incorporate the XPath into the Selenium/Python command listed below, I receive an error message:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='id_past_appointments']/tbody /tr/td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]//following-sibling::*[9]/div/a[2]").click()
```

Cannot figure out why the Selenium Python command causes an error message.

Comment: Post the complete error message. There is no error or exception in the message you posted.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've mixed up two identifiers.

You've checked this xpath:

```
.//*[@id='id_past_appointments']//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]]//a[normalize-space(.)='View Note']
```

But you use this one in your code:

```
.//[@id='id_past_appointments']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]//following-sibling::[9]/div/a[2]
```